# Convert UTF-16 text to another encoding (Windows-1250) 

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I have a text in a variable, **text**, encoded in the default (UTF-16) encoding. I would like to change it to [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250). I have:

```
public static string EncodeToWin1250(string text)
{
    Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
    Encoding win1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);

    byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] win1250Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, win1250, unicodeBytes);

    char[] win1250Chars = new char[win1250.GetCharCount(win1250Bytes, 0, win1250Bytes.Length)];
    win1250.GetChars(win1250Bytes, 0, win1250Bytes.Length, win1250Chars, 0);
    text = new string(win1250Chars);
    return text;
}
```

but so far it doesn't work.

How do I fix this problem?

I am returning the string as a file:

```
[...]
result = BLL.DataExchange.MoneyS3.MoneyS3Export.EncodeToWin1250(result);
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=invoicesIssued.xml");
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
Context.Response.Write(result);
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.Close();
```

Comment: A string object in C# is always Unicode. Where do you need the other encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All strings are stored internally as Unicode in .NET.

You can convert a string to a byte stream using a codepage, as your code does. But your can't change the internal representation of the string: It's Unicode (encoded as UTF16), period.

You may dump your encoded byte stream to a file or wherever you want. But you can't change the internal encoding of .NET string objects.

Your function should return a `byte[]` instead of a string (`win1250Chars` actually)

Comment: Editted the main post. Thanks for reply